# Graph not sorting correct

Tags: r, graph

I am trying to make a graph with data from a excel(.csv) file. When I run the file the line sorts incorrectly. I want it to sort on the date. It starts at 1 september 2020(1-9-2020) and ends on 1 june 2021(1-6-2021).
This is the graph i get. You can not have a descending line, you can only gain point not subtract point you already earned.:
[incorrectly sorted graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiITh.png)

This is the excel file: [Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2oLN.png)

And this is the code I use:

```
library(ggplot2)


punten_data <- read.csv("Studiepunten.csv", sep = ";")
punten_data$datum <- as.Date(punten_data$datum)

ggplot(punten_data, aes(x = datum, y = studiepunten, group = 1)) + 
geom_line()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Please post the output from `dput(punten_data)` rather than a link to an Excel file.  Help us to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the format for your date, as follow:

```
as.Date(c("1-9-2020", "1-10-2020", "1-1-2021"), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

You can also preview the date of your file before trying to order them too, it will help you to make sure they were correctly transformed to date.

```
head(punten_data$datum)
```

Best,
Rosalie

Comment: Thank you very much!!